# Directory disappears after test concludes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I'm trying to put the output of a UnitTest in an *intellgent* location so I can:

- Run the test multiple times and either overwrite or create new results
- Find the results / trace / log files I create
- Avoid hard coding the path

The advice seems to be to use TestContext (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcontext?view=mstest-net-1.2.0).  My unit test correctly populates this object; I can see that as I'm debugging.

I've tried writing to several files and come up with *frustrating* results.

**Write to a file in the Test Directory**

```
            string fileOutput = Path.Combine(m_testContext.TestDir, "readmeBasic.txt");
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fileOutput))
            {
                file.WriteLine("Basic Data");
                ...
            }
```

**Write a trace message**

```
            m_testContext.WriteLine("Test Directory " + m_testContext.TestDir);
```

When I execute my code, I can see the `readmeBasic.txt` appear.  Using Notepad++ during execution of the unit test, the file appears empty even after several `WriteLine` statements.  After successful, error free execution of my unit test, the directory with the file gets removed (by Visual Studio ???).

- Is there a configuration I'm missing?
- Where is there documentation that explains why this directory gets removed?
- What is the point of providing this information in `m_testcontext` if it is transient and will get removed?

***Visual Studio 2019 16.3.9***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the deployment folder will be deleted by default when the test runs

successfully.

If you want to save the folder, you could create a runsettings file, then set “DeleteDeploymentDirectoryAfterTestRunIsComplete” to false, the configuration will retain the deployment folder after a test run.

Please follow [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?view=vs-2019) to create a runsetting file, then type the below code:

In addition, the ”Testcontext” is used to get some information of running test, such as test name, test outcome and etc. The testcontext.writeline will write into test output, which will input to trx file, so you may need to use file.writeline() to record trace message.

[image]

BTW, you could refer this sample about logging current TestMethod with result:

```
[TestCleanup]
    public void LogResult()
    {

        var testOutcome = TestContext.CurrentTestOutcome;
        string testName = TestContext.TestName;
        string testdir = Path.Combine(TestContext.TestDir,"log.txt");

        string str = testName + ": " + testOutcome.ToString() + "\n";

        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(testdir))
        {
            file.WriteLine(str);
            file.WriteLine("Basic Data");
        }
    }

    public TestContext TestContext
    {
        get { return testContextInstance; }
        set { testContextInstance = value; }
    }

    private TestContext testContextInstance;
```